# Using axios or async network call in the actions of the redux, updating the initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am developing a Web application using React + Redux. What I am doing now is I am making a API request using the Axios network library. I do not want to make the asyc API call in the component. As a book I am reading recommended, I am making the call in the actions.

This is my actions.

```
export const EVENT_START_FETCHING_LIST = "(EVENT) request list start";
export const EVENT_COMPLETE_FETCHING_LIST = "(EVENT) request list completed";
export const EVENT_THROW_ERROR_FETCHING_LIST = "(EVENT) request list throw error";
import { getHttpClient } from '../memento/getHttpClient';

export const startFetchingEvents = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        getHttpClient().get('event/list').then((response) => {
            dispatch(completeFetchingEvents(response.data));
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(throwErrorFetchingEvents({ message: "Error in fetching events from the server", styleClass: "alert alert-danger" }));
        })        
    }
}

export const completeFetchingEvents = (data) => {
    return {
        type : EVENT_COMPLETE_FETCHING_LIST,
        payload : data
    }
}

export const throwErrorFetchingEvents = (data) => {
    return {
        type : EVENT_THROW_ERROR_FETCHING_LIST,
        payload : data
    }
}
```

If I want to make the call, I just trigger the action like this in the component.

```
 this.props.startFetchingEvents()
```

The problem I am having is that updating the state. I have a property in the state, called "loading.". This is my reducer.

```
import * as EventListActions from '../actions/event.list.actions';

const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    message: null,
    events: []
}

export default function (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EventListActions.EVENT_START_FETCHING_LIST:
            {
                //TODO: this event is not triggerd
                return { ...state, loading: true, events: [], message: null };
            }

        case EventListActions.EVENT_COMPLETE_FETCHING_LIST:
            {
                return { ...state, loading: false, events: action.payload };
            }

        case EventListActions.EVENT_THROW_ERROR_FETCHING_LIST:
            {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    message: {

                    }
                }
            }
    }
    return state;
}
```

As you can see in my reducer, I am updating the loading value to true, when the API called is made. But as I commented, that function is not triggered. Other functions are triggered. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not dispatching the `EVENT_START_FETCHING_LIST` action type. You can do it like this:

```
export const startFetchingEvents = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
          type : EVENT_START_FETCHING_LIST,
        });

        return getHttpClient().get('event/list').then((response) => {
            dispatch(completeFetchingEvents(response.data));
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(throwErrorFetchingEvents({ message: "Error in fetching events from the server", styleClass: "alert alert-danger" }));
        })        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

It seems simple. You forgot to dispatch it...

```
export const startFetchingEvents = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(startFetchingEvents());
        getHttpClient().get('event/list').then((response) => {
            dispatch(completeFetchingEvents(response.data));
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(throwErrorFetchingEvents({ message: "Error in fetching events from the server", styleClass: "alert alert-danger" }));
        })        
    }
} 

const startFetchingEvents = () => {
    return {
        type : EVENT_START_FETCHING_LIST
    }
}
```